# why bootstrap tour not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-tour

hi I want user bootstrap tour in my project to create some help. I write the code just like the sample. but the code not worked correctly.
in other word as soon as my page load the first step is show even without click the help button. also the back, next and end button not shows. like this image:

[image]

also I get this error in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'getTipElement')
> at o._showPopover (bootstrap-tour.min.js:22:12052)
> at o._showPopoverAndOverlay (bootstrap-tour.min.js:22:11093)
> at o._showPopoverAndOverlay (bootstrap-tour.min.js:22:51)
> at HTMLBodyElement. (bootstrap-tour.min.js:22:13449)
> at r.complete (jquery.min.js:2:62910)
> at c (jquery.min.js:2:28327)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:29072)
> at u (jquery.min.js:2:59642)
> at S.fx.tick (jquery.min.js:2:64608)
> at ot (jquery.min.js:2:58967)

I use the bootstrap 5.3.2 version.
this is my button code:

```
<button id="SiteTour" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-floating btn-lg border-success position-fixed rounded-circle hvr hvr-grow"
        style="bottom: 70px; right: 20px; z-index:1000;" data-SiteTour>
 help
</button>
```

and this is my JavaScript sample code:

```
<script>
    // Instance the tour
    var tour = new Tour({
        steps: [
            {
                element: "#sectionText",
                title: "Title of my step",
                content: "Content of my step"
            },
            {
                element: "#MainBody",
                title: "Title of my step",
                content: "Content of my step"
            }
        ]
    });

    // Initialize the tour
    tour.init();

    // Start the tour
    tour.start();
</script>
```

how can fix this? please help.